# Count the no. of pairs in a list

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to figure out a function that looks at a list of words that might belong to 1 or 2 categories, and counts the no. of each category pair - please refer to the screenshot for example. Tips?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to replace the string categories with numbers, and work with that (I took out the duplicate line in the results table):

[image]

There is one intermediate calculation column, which I haven't found a simple way to avoid (Excel doesn't seem to like two different length arrays in one array formula: but someone may have a way around that).

Here are the two formula cells (which use array functions):
[image]

If you have more than 9 categories, replace the 10 in both formulae with 100.

If you have to use text category names, then use a lookup table.